# How I found the value

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I would like to know how to find the value of a function.

For example, consider one the most basic funcions

```
y[x] = x^2
```

The ploy is a parabola. So if I want y = 1200, I need to see on the graph approximate values to test for x to find it.

My questions is, in mathematica is there a function or any command where I can write y = 1200 and automatically generate the value of x?

Comment: Try [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)` like `Solve[1200 == x^2, x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is always `Solve` (also `NSolve`). As @Jason showed, using `Solve` with a specific value will give you all possible solutions

```
f[x_] = x^2
Solve[f[x] == 1.2, x]
```

> {{x -> -1.09545}, {x -> 1.09545}}

On the other hand as @Mark showed,

```
Solve[y == f[x], x]
```

> {{x -> -Sqrt[y]}, {x -> Sqrt[y]}}

will give you all possible analytical solutions which you can use to generate values of x for any y. However these methods can be tricky when you have large and complicated functions (specially trigonometric functions where you might have to specify the domain like `0<x<2Pi` as well). In that case you can use `FindRoot`

```
FindRoot[f[x] == 1.2, {x, 1.0}]
FindRoot[f[x] == 1.2, {x, -1.0}]
```

> {x -> 1.09545}
> {x -> -1.09545}

`FindRoot` requires an initial guess and gives only one numerical solution closest to the initial guess.

Comment: Thanks for help me